# "npm list -g" returns nothing despite having globally installed packages

Tags: npm

Running `npm list -g` returns nothing even though I've installed packages globally.

```
npm root -g 
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules

ls `npm root -g`
> @elements   interact.js npm         npm-run-all react       tsd         tslint      typescript

npm list -g
> # nothing
```

Do I need to set `NODE_PATH`? It's currently unset. Maybe there's some other setting that I've misconfigured. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Removed my previous comment, because I saw you've checked root.  What happens when you try ***npm config get prefix***?

Comment: `npm config get prefix` returns `/usr/local`

Comment: Ok, try updating your npm config prefix.  `npm config edit` then update the  `prefix=/usr/local/lib`

Comment: So I just did npm config set prefix '/usr/local/lib', still nothing :(

Comment: I guess you could try adding that dir to your NODE_PATH as well then (make sure to restart shell). `NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"`

Comment: I am very interested in your question . Have you found the reason?

Comment: Nope, I never did find the reason behind this. I still have the same `npm config` and it just magically started working after upgrading npm one day.