# npm ls -g empty after installing package globally

Tags: windows, npm, npm-install, git-bash, msysgit

I normally develop on *nix, so I'm a little out of my element, but trying to assist a fellow Windows developer with npm. Using Git Bash (MSYSGIT), we installed the latest version of npm with:

```
$ npm install -g npm
```

Before this, the package directory was empty. But now we can see the package in the directory:

```
$ ls /c/Users/steve.jobs/AppData/Roaming/npm
npm
```

However, npm for some reason doesn't detect the package:

```
$ npm ls -g --depth=0
C:\Users\steve.jobs\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)
```

What gives?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36843513/1015595